# mat-menu and button in different components

Tags: angular-cli, angular-material2

I have

```
<mat-menu #saveMenu="matMenu">...</mat-menu>
```

in app-save-document component and

```
<app-save-document></app-save-document>
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="saveMenu">
```

in another component.

if I have mat-menu and button with [matMenuTriggerFor] in different components, can I do something to make the button see the menu?

now I have `ERROR Error: mat-menu-trigger: must pass in an mat-menu instance.`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Well, if you want to do something like this:

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<other-component [matMenu]="menu"></other-component>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

You can code `<other-component>` like this:

```typescript
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {MatMenu} from '@angular/material/menu';

@Component({
  selector: 'other-component',
  template: `
    This button is in another component:
    <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="matMenu">Click here to open menu</button>
  `,
})
export class OtherComponent {
  @Input() matMenu: MatMenu;
}
```

You can see the above example working at this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma4834389864331661).

---

### Another approach

Another approach is (I think this is what you want): your *trigger button* is **inside the parent** (but **outside the child**) and the *menu* itself is defined **inside the child** component.

**Parent component:**

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="childComponentMenu?.menu">
    Menu in other component
</button>
<child-component></child-component>
```

```typescript
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponentMenu: ChildComponent;
}
```

**Child Component:**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <mat-menu>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1 (inside other component)</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2 (inside other component)</button>
    </mat-menu>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatMenu, {static: true}) menu: MatMenu;
}
```

---

### Yet Another approach

Another approach, similar to the above one, but using template reference variables (notice the `exportAs` in the decorator of the child component):

**Parent component:**

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="x.menu">
    Menu in other component
</button>
<child-component #x="menuInOtherComponent"></child-component>

export class ParentComponent {
}
```

**Child Component:**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <mat-menu>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1 (inside other component)</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2 (inside other component)</button>
    </mat-menu>
  `,
  exportAs: 'menuInOtherComponent',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatMenu, {static: true}) menu: MatMenu;
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma4834389864331662)

Comment: Thanks for the multiple approaches. The third one is my preferred method.

Comment: thanks you, like it's said, the third one is the perfect one. First time I encountered the exportAs property though !

Comment: You don't need `exportAs` for the 3rd one. Just use `[matMenuTriggerFor]="x.menu"` and `<child-component #x>`

Comment: In fact, `exportAs` makes more sense with directives (as you can have multiple directives being applied to a component), but to keep it consistent, I like to use it in both cases, with components and directives. Not using it could indeed let the answer code simpler, but I'll stick to this more angular.io-documented-like approach. :)

Comment: what if wanted to place only the buttons in the child component?

Comment: @Lonely, this case is already in my answer under the title "ANOTHER APPROACH".

Comment: @jpavel I mean without `<mat-menu>`in the child component that I had to implement it today (= 4th approach) and it has also worked,..

Comment: I am just here to say thanks
The second option was the one I used

Comment: If anyone wants to trigger that child menu from parent menu option on "mouseenter" try this code: 

`<button mat-menu-item #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" (mouseenter)="menuTrigger.openMenu()"
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="x.menu">`

Comment: Looks like since angular 9 need to specify `static: true` for ViewChild.
```@ViewChild(MatMenu, {static: true}) menu: MatMenu;```

Comment: @АнтонДосов, just in angular 8 you need that. In angular 9 it's optional.

Comment: @julianobrasil, in angular 9 default has changed from {static: true} to {static: false}. If not specify {static: true} in angular 9, then this demo would likely have an error in console.

I didn't check this demo, but this is what I saw in my codebase.

Comment: @АнтонДосов, thanks. I've updated the demos to angular 9.

Comment: If I want to close the menu on clicking on cross icon which is the part of menu, then how to do that?

Comment: @VikramSapate, what do you mean by "part of menu"? Anyway, you can always close the menu programmatically if you have a reference to the instance you want to close (or to the instance of the trigger directive)

Comment: I am still getting the error : matMenuTriggerFor: must pass in an mat-menu instance for the "Another Approch" @julianobrasil. Can anyone know the reason? Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering why they had `="matMenu"` on `#menu` in the documentation. thanks!

Comment: If you get `Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member 'MatMenu'.ts(2305)`. The MatMenu import is now like this: `import { MatMenu } from '@angular/material/menu';`

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution using `ng-content`. That's my preferred way to go.

my-custom-menu-component html:

```html
<div [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  menu content
</mat-menu>
```

parent-component html:

```html
<my-custom-menu-component>
  <button>click me</button>
<my-custom-menu-component>
```

Comment: How is that button hooking into the menu?

Comment: It looks like the end product has an invisible `div` with a click handler wrapped around the actual button.  This doesn't feel like sound design to me -- the `matMenuTriggerFor` attribute really should be attached to a button, not a div.

Answer (score 0):

I was using @julianobrasil's second approach but in my case, my requirement was to close dialog on clicking on cross icon which is in the menu component (child-component).
So, used this approch...

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{ 'data': 'someData' }">

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [hasBackdrop]="false">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-data="data">
    <child-comp 
      (close)="onCloseMenu()"
      [input-to-child-comp]="data"
    >
    </child-comp>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

**[hasBackdrop]="false"** avoid closing menu on outside click.

I've used **ng-template** to pass some data to child menu component.

In the child component I've used one button to close the menu,

```
  <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined" (click)="closeMenu()">close</maticon>
```

In closeMenu function just emitting close event, to close the menu,

```
 @Output() close = new EventEmitter();
  closeMenu() {
    this.close.emit();
  }
```

In parent compoent,

```
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) menu: MatMenuTrigger;
  onCloseMenu() {
    this.menu.closeMenu();
  }
```

& it's working fine.